# Check tests compile without running them or creating a binary

Tags: unit-testing, go

How with Go can I check that my tests compile without creating any binaries or executing the tests?

The test equivalent of `go build ./...`, which does this but ignores tests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use any non-matching regex for the run flag, like

```
go test -run NONE ./...
```

or set `-count=0`

```
go test -count=0 ./...
```

Comment: Ideally you could use `go test -c -o /dev/null` but the go tool doesn't let you specify `/dev/null`. Personally I just put `go test -c` as my editor's "make" command and don't worry about the `pkg.test` file it produces.